# Tradier API websockets stream node.js example is not receiving any events

Tags: websocket, nodes, tradier

I have the following nodejs code per [this](https://documentation.tradier.com/brokerage-api/streaming/create-market-session) and [this](https://documentation.tradier.com/brokerage-api/streaming/wss-market-websocket):

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.tradier.com/v1/markets/events');

request({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://api.tradier.com/v1/markets/events/session',
  form: {
    
  },
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_API_KEY_NOT_SHOWN',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
}, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
    let data = JSON.parse(body)
    let sessionId = data.stream.sessionid
    streamPrice(sessionId)
});

function streamPrice(sessionId){
  console.log(sessionId)
  ws.on('open', function open() {
    console.log('Connected, sending subscription commands...');
    ws.send(`{"symbols": ["TSLA"], "sessionid": "${sessionId}", "linebreak": true}`);
  });
  ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  ws.on('error', function error(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

I get a `200 OK` back from the API request to create the web sockets session, and I have a valid session ID:

```
200
{"stream":{"url":"https:\/\/stream.tradier.com\/v1\/markets\/events","sessionid":"6ba4158d-8ff8-46c3-b005-***********"}}
6ba4158d-8ff8-46c3-b005-***********
```

However, the `ws.on()` events never fire. I am not getting any errors. The session does close after a period of time, presumably due to inactivity. But it's not inactivity on my code's part...

Is there something wrong in my code / something I'm missing to make this work?

Comment: maybe your ws.on('open', doesn't trigger because the websocket is already open. Maybe running  ws.send( directly in the streamPrice function body will work.

Comment: @user3791775 I removed the ws.on('open', altogether, leaving only the ws.send( in place and now the stock stream is flying in! Thank you!

Comment: Ok nice to hear that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to identify the issue myself. The problem is I was opening the websocket too early.

I moved the following line inside of `streamingPrice` scope instead of the global scope to resolve.

```
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.tradier.com/v1/markets/events');
```